# How do I set certain checkboxes of a checkedcomboboxedit UI item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, editor, devexpress

How do I set certain checkboxes of a [CheckedComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic) UI item? This is for DevExpress. So if I have a drop down of 5 check boxes, and I want just two of the checkboxes in the drop down to be checked when the form loads, what would the C# code look like?

Answer (score 3):

Once your data is loaded into the [CheckedComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic) you would need to do something like:

```
checkedComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items[0].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
checkedComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items[3].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
```

That would mark the 1st and 4th items in the list as checked.

Related help article: [CheckedListBoxItem.CheckState](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsCheckedListBoxItem_CheckStatetopic)

Comment: If the items are string values, you can look up the item by string instead: `checkedComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items["Onions"].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;`

Answer (score -1):

chccmbobox_username.Properties.SeparatorChar = ";"

Dim st As String = ""

For Each model As TicketModel In result

```
st += model.User_LongName & ";"
```

Next

chccmbobox_username.SetEditValue(st)